# How to change the non-editable foreground for JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, look-and-feel

I want to change the non-editable foreground (to avoid  incomprehensibility `JTextComponent.setEditable(false)`) for all text fields in my application but failed to found an appropriate property key for `UIManager` to do it. Is it possible to change the non-editable foreground globally?

Comment: Which look and feel?

Comment: Main goal is Synthetica, but it's intresting to know whether it's possible at all.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've got answer from Jyloo: Synthetica will support it from the next release.

Comment: thats really significant difference textfield and JTextComponents, for plain (JTexField/Area) is valid answer by @MadProgrammer for rest is different, and type by type

Comment: DYM taht standard disableXxxColor doesn't works or is/aren't this/those nested/inherits method(s) implemented from JTextComponents, I'm doubt in it, this L&F is comparable with Substance (has own Renderer/painters)

Comment: @mKorbel I've wrote JTextComponent because the method is defined in this class. But need to change the foreground for JTextField and JFormattedTextField.

Answer (score 2):

Under "normal" look and feels, you could using the `"TextField.inactiveBackground"` key, for the text, you would use `"TextField.inactiveForeground"`

for example

```
UIManager.put("TextField.inactiveBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));
```

Look and feels like Nimbus might require some "additional" work...

[image: NonEditableTextFied]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;

public class NonEdtiableField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                UIManager.put("TextField.inactiveBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                JTextField editable = new JTextField(10);
                JTextField nonEditable = new JTextField(10);
                nonEditable.setEditable(false);
                frame.add(editable);
                frame.add(nonEditable);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: there are two states editable and enabled, I'm not sure which one OP means

Comment: meaning setDisabledTextColor

Comment: I took *"non-editable foreground"* to mean editable state, but having the `disabledTextColor` property mentioned is also a good idea

Comment: Want to switch foreground after using of 'JTextComponent.setEditable(false)'

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Yep, as I said, you can use `TextField.inactiveForeground` as well

Answer (score 2):

Solution found:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTextFieldUI;

/**
 * <code>ExtSynthTextFieldUI</code>.
 *
 * @author SMedvynskyy
 */
public class ExtSynthTextFieldUI extends SynthTextFieldUI {

    /** Handler to change foreground when editable status changed. */
    private final PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

        /** Save the old color here. */
        private Color standardColor = UIManager.getColor(getPropertyPrefix() + ".foreground");

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ("editable".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(evt.getNewValue())) {
                    getComponent().setForeground(standardColor);
                } else {
                    standardColor = getComponent().getForeground();
                    // set the "inactive foreground"
                    getComponent().setForeground(new ColorUIResource(0xA0A0A0));
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Creates a new UI object for the given component.
     *
     * @param table component to create UI object for
     * @return the UI object
     */
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent table) {
        return new ExtSynthTextFieldUI();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void installListeners() {
        super.installListeners();
        getComponent().addPropertyChangeListener("editable", listener);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void uninstallListeners() {
        getComponent().removePropertyChangeListener("editable", listener);
        super.uninstallListeners();
    }
}
```

After installing of L&F I simply need to reset the default UI:

```
UIManager.put("TextFieldUI", ExtSynthTextFieldUI.class.getName());
```

Comment: there isn't required PropertyChangeListener, quite useless, only in the case that you want to wrap, to decorate Swing inside Html and with something special, thats build at rumtime, volatile, cached

Comment: @mKorbel UI must install listener to be notified when a property of the wrapped object is changed. Otherwise I need to replace all the JTextField objects in our application by my extension class.